# How to query mongodb with a LIKE (regex) in a route of node.js?

Tags: node.js, regex, api

Iam using node.js to make a API to query mongodb database.
On the mongo I have the field: timestamp with values: `2021-02-04T00:27:04.505-0300` for example.

On my route I just want to get all entries with the portion `2021-02-04`, I try using regex on the route but it's not working.

Can anyone give me a tip to query mongodb using regex on route query ?
the param `:dia` is where I want to do the regex, the URL I call is:

`http://127.0.0.0.1:3400/vulns/severity/server01/2021-02-04/High`

(Then I expect the to get all `vulns` from `server01` with `High` severity from day `2021-02-04`.)

My route code is below, I put `/req.params.dia/` but it's not recognized like a regex:

```
router.get('/severity/:name/:dia/:sev', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const logues = await vulnerability.find({'agent.name': req.params.name,'timestamp': /req.params.dia/,'data.vulnerability.severity': req.params.sev});
    res.json(logues)
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json({ message: err.message })
  }
})
```

On the mongodb appears this query when I try to use the API:

```
[conn177] command XXX.vulnerabilities command: find { find: "vulnerabilities", filter: { agent.name: "server01", timestamp: /req.params.dia/, data.vulnerability.severity: "High" }, projection: {}, returnKey: false, showRecordId: false } planSummary: COLLSCAN keysExamined:0 docsExamined:6279 cursorExhausted:1 keyUpdates:0 writeConflicts:0 numYields:49 nreturned:0 reslen:128 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 100 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 50 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { r: 50 } } } protocol:op_query 15ms
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume your `timestamp` field in MongoDB is of type Date; e.g. your `2021-02-04T00:27:04.505-0300` is just a string representation. In that case you need to search a Date, which is done by range. Fro a single day, the range is from the zero second of the day to to zero second of the next day:

```
router.get('/severity/:name/:dia/:sev', async (req, res) => {
  let startDate = new Date(req.params.dia + 'T00:00:00Z'); // '021-02-04' becomes '021-02-04T00:00:00Z'
  let endDate = new Date(startDate.valueOf());
  endDate.setDate(endDate.getDate() + 1);
  try {
    const logues = await vulnerability.find({
        'agent.name': req.params.name,
        'timestamp': /req.params.dia/,
        timestamp: {
          $gte: startDate,
          $lt:  endDate
        }
        'data.vulnerability.severity': req.params.sev
    });
    res.json(logues)
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json({ message: err.message })
  }
})
```

Comment: I worked fine for me, thanks for the help!

Comment: I vote it but looks (has a new user here) i have not sufficient reputation to upvote.

Comment: Ah, understood.